# Download .deb packages for different os version + architecture with apt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I've got a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04, and an iMac 8, 1 with Ubuntu 20.04 server.
The server one ironically doesn't have wifi (which I cannot figure out), but the laptop does.

Is there any way I can use apt to download all the arm64 Ubuntu 20 versions of all the deb files I need? I just have to get those files then I can put them on the iMac and get fluxbox (I'm trying to set it up to run Pico-8 but Gnome is too intensive for it so regular Ubuntu doesn't install)

Tried using

```
apt-cache depends fluxbox | grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y
```

on the laptop (Ubuntu 22 and i386), but it (predictably) downloaded the Ubuntu 22 i386 versions of those packages.

Thanks!

Edit: I just connected the iMac and my laptop with an ethernet cable and let it use my laptop's wifi. Works like a charm!

Comment: Do you know what packages you need? Also from what I can tell, the iMAC 8,1 is x86, possibly 32 bit as opposed to 64 bit. Could you add your uname -a output to the question?

Comment: It says x86_64, but when I try to install the all the dependencies for fluxbox, some of them tell me package architecture (i386) does not match system (arm64) (It was on libc6 was the one I was able to catch).
The stuff I need is fluxbox, all it's dependencies, and their dependencies. It's a huge list which is why I'd rather have a way to do this besides manually.

here are the .deb files it gives me when I run that apt-cache command on the laptop.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pwVqIMIOzVi8AbaKpMrfSrORWiblD8Xl/view?usp=sharing 
it was too long a list for character limit sorry

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has "the solution" in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using one of apt proxy packages [approx, apt-cacher, apt-cacher-ng] (or even http proxy)?

It should allow comp without (direct) internet access to download packages it needs *and keep them up to date*.